# How to pass data between two cells (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view with multiple different cells, and one of the cells depends on property of another one. I.e. I have FirstCell, which has dynamic property `count`, and I have SecondCell, which contains several UITextFields. I want the number of these UITextFields to match the `count` property. How can I get `count` property from FirstCell considering that this property can be changed?

I.g. FirstCell contains `count = 3`, SecondCell shows three UITextFields. Property `count` changes to value `4` and another one UITextField appears in SecondCell.

Comment: Do you have the design for these cells? Then may be I can help you with that. Otherwise its very difficult to create the logic without any UI design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of count should be in your data model. You add an observer, or put code into the setter, so when the value of count is changed, the two cells depending on it (the one displaying count, and the one showing the text fields) are both reloaded; that's reloadCellAtIndexPaths or something like that from memory.

Obviously the code that loads cells must be written correctly, and code changing count in the first cell must change the model property.

Answer (score 0):

Thinks like this should be managed by the `UI(Table)ViewController`. The view controller should be notified when the text field changes (for example using target-action) and then update the data source and reload the relevant cells.